# How to get/put files from SFTP server using Net::SSH::Perl module?

Tags: perl, ssh

It might be simple query, but still I'm not clear regarding this.

In my script I'm connecting to SFTP client server using [`Net::SSH::Perl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aPerl) module. Previously I was using [`Net::SFTP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSFTP) but removed from the script, as all of a sudden it stopped working and throwing an error.

When I used `Net::SFTP`, most often I will use the below command to Put/get files from remote server.

```
$sftp->put("/home/ftpford/ftpcon/conout/$file","/Uti_Integrator/READYFORPICKUP/PENDING/$file");
```

But I'm not sure of how to get/put files using `Net::SSH::Perl`.
Can any one suggest? I have tried many ways and even I tried to search in Google but I'm not clear of any thing.

And please note that I don't have privileges to install new modules in my server.
I want to get/put files using the above Module.

Comment: What error message are you getting with Net::SFTP?

Comment: Hi @JohnC below is the error.
"No matching cipher found: client 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour server aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SSH/Perl/SSH2.pm line 92 Can't locate object method "_session_channel" via package "Net::SSH::Perl::SSH1" at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SFTP.pm line 78. Can't locate object method "_session_channel" via package "Net::SSH::Perl::SSH1" at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SFTP.pm line 78."

Comment: That seems to imply that Net::SFTP uses Net::SSH::Perl, but that the problem is that Net::SSH::Perl can't connect because there are no common ciphers.

Comment: Yes, it says that the server only supports AES ciphers, while Net::SSH::Perl does not support AES ciphers. Someone must have changed the configuration of the ssh server. Ask the admin if he can reverse those changes to allow one of your supported ciphers (3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour).

Comment: Hi @jcaron is there a possibility that all of a sudden we will face these kind of errors. Because it used to work perfectly few days ago (almost since 1 year). Is there a way to resolve this issue? It is affecting whole file transmission. Now I'm in confused state of how to proceed regarding this. As Net::SFTP is throwing error and can't able to install new modules (don't know how to get new modules to my own directory in Unix server).

Comment: Hi @jcaron Can you please clarify whether these CIPHERS should be changed on Client server or My Unix server? I was not clear with your above post sorry!

Comment: Net::SSH::Perl has limited cipher support, so you can't enable additional ciphers, all those that are included are already enabled. So it needs to be changed (back) on the server, which apparently used to support one of those ciphers (3DES, Blowfish and RC4) but doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a standard feature of Net::SSH::Perl.

One option is to use other modules that do (you don't necessarily need to install them in the system directories, you can have them in your own directories if you include them via `PERL5LIB` or `use lib`.

The other option (which answers your question *stricto sensu*) is to emulate it. You can try to simply run `cat >$destination_file` on the remote box via Net::SSH::Perl, and then send the contents of the file over the ssh connection.

Of course, error handling and the like might not be very straightforward...

BTW, you tell us you have tried many things, but you don't tell us which, and what problems you encountered.

Comment: Hi @jcaron I have tried installing other modules like Net::OpenSSH and Net::SCP  but no luck. And I tried below 
$ssh2->cmd("cp /home/ftpford/ftpcon/conout/$file /Uti_Integrator/SOH REPORTS/PENDING/$file")
And again I tried with Net::SFTP and could see the below error. Still I was confused how come all of a sudden I'm getting below error when using Net::SFTP, which used to be working perfectly.

Comment: Error as below:

"No matching cipher found: client 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour server aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SSH/Perl/SSH2.pm line 92
Can't locate object method "_session_channel" via package "Net::SSH::Perl::SSH1" at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SFTP.pm line 78.
Can't locate object method "_session_channel" via package "Net::SSH::Perl::SSH1" at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SFTP.pm line 78."